# Loading animation when using .load in jquery

Tags: jquery, load

I have an issue here that I can't solve by myself.

Im loading an .html page with jquery .load and want to have an loading image while loading the page. It works just fine when I run the page without loading the HTML page, then it works just fine. I have tried to put the load function in the loaded html file but then it's never ends even though the page is fully loaded.

My code looks like this:

```
 $(window).load(function(){
 $('#loading').fadeOut(2000);
 });

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.menuBtn').click(function(event) {

$("#slidePage").load($(this).attr('name'));

$('#mainPage').animate({"right": "100%"}, function(){
         $("#mainPage").hide();
    }); 
});
```

I have tried to have the loading div in the .html and the main file, same issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Seem's you are looking for something like this -

```
$('#loading').fadeIn(2000);
$("#slidePage").load($(this).attr('name'),function(){
 $('#loading').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Comment: I got the same result as before. I suppose you want me to replace this rows with "$("#slidePage").load($(this).attr('name'));" and remove the window load?

Comment: It kinda does what I want but the problem now is that the loading bar disappear before the .html file is fully loaded.

Comment: Do you have `#slidePage` hidden before loading html ?

Comment: No, it's not. If I hide it before I get the same result.